# correct use of colors in scatterpie

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatterpie

I want to make 6 different pies using scatterpie.  There are 101 different categories making up the pies (not all pies have 101), so I want to be able to differentiate the colors.

This does not give me enough colors (I can tell just by looking at the pies)

```
ggplot(wholebody_cutLH_wide_t) +
#  annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) +
geom_scatterpie(aes(x=imX, y=imY,r=radius),
            data=wholebody_cutLH_wide_t,     cols=colnames(wholebody_cutLH_wide_t[1:101]),color=NA) +
#scale_color_manual(values=sample(allcolors,101)) +
 scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), lim=c(0,3)) +
scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), lim=c(0,6)) +
theme(legend.position="none",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent") # bg of the panel
    , plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent") # bg of the plot
    , panel.grid.major = element_blank() # get rid of major grid
    , panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), # get rid of minor grid
    line = element_blank(),
    text = element_blank(),
    title = element_blank()
)
```

[image]

Then if I try to set the colors manually as below I get a blank screen.
If I try and set the colors in the scatterpie (color=sample(allcolors,101)), then I get the error

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2864): colour

```
allcolors = grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y', grDevices::colors(), invert = T)]
ggplot(wholebody_cutLH_wide_t) +
#  annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) +
geom_scatterpie(aes(x=imX, y=imY,r=radius),
            data=wholebody_cutLH_wide_t, cols=colnames(wholebody_cutLH_wide_t[1:101]),color=NA) +
scale_color_manual(values=sample(allcolors,101)) +
scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), lim=c(0,3)) +
scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), lim=c(0,6)) +
theme(legend.position="none",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent") # bg of the panel
    , plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent") # bg of the plot
    , panel.grid.major = element_blank() # get rid of major grid
    , panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), # get rid of minor grid
    line = element_blank(),
    text = element_blank(),
    title = element_blank()
 )
```

Comment: Are you sure that `colnames(wholebody_cutLH_wide_t[1:101])` is correct ? Or should it be `colnames(wholebody_cutLH_wide_t)[1:101]` ?

Comment: strange, yes the bracket was in the wrong place, but correcting it doesn't change the plot

Comment: you are correct, I misplaced the brackets, but when I fix it there is still the same problem with the lack of colors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the final working code.  I had to switch the scale_color_manual to scale_fill_manual.

```
ggplot(wholebody_cutLH_wide_t) +
annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) +
geom_scatterpie(aes(x=imX, y=imY,r=radius),
            data=wholebody_cutLH_wide_t, cols=colnames(wholebody_cutLH_wide_t)[1:101],color=NA) +
scale_fill_manual(values=sample(allcolors,101)) +
scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), lim=c(0,3)) +
scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), lim=c(0,6)) +
theme(legend.position="none",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent") # bg of the panel
    , plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent") # bg of the plot
    , panel.grid.major = element_blank() # get rid of major grid
    , panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), # get rid of minor grid
    line = element_blank(),
    text = element_blank(),
    title = element_blank()
)
```

And here is the plot

[image]